# Knocking out the barrier between fridge and freezer?

Tags: temperature-control, serving, help, projects

I have a fridge freezer combo that I am going to convert to a serving fridge. I have done this with an old fridge before but decided to upgrade when I moved because it was really old and crapping out.

**Question:**
What will happen if I cut out the majority of the barrier between the fridge and freezer? I'm concerned about everything freezing, or over/under using the refrigeration unit.

**Why:**
2 reasons, first I really want my taps at a reasonable height, second, I really think the extra height would reduce the clutter of beer and gas lines and make everything easier to manage.

**Notes:** I really don't want to use a secondary temp controller, will the fridge's temp controller work ok?

**The Fridge I Have:**
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_5ZSGtMB-F0

Comment: I think this might be off topic for this site. While it's indirectly related to brewing, the key skills are not brewing, but fridge maintainance and hacking. I'll leave it here for a few days to see if it picks up any answers here, and later migrate to another site to help get more answers afterwards.

Comment: What do you know about the construction of this fridge? Are you sure there are no wires or coolant pipes within that barrier?

Comment: Logic says that if you turn down the temperature enough, your stuff will not freeze. But, your freezer will determine the temp and if it is a newer fridge with dual temp controls, it may cause the fridge to stop working.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that this is going to work very well, stripping out the barrier between the freezer and the refrigerator.  Any number of things could happen:

- You risk damaging the refrigerant lines that may pass between or go around the freezer portion,
- Unless you can disable the freezer, you may find it working extra hard to try and maintain the thermostat temperature of the freezer area, which could possibly result in damaging the freezer components,
- Could end up with additional and unwanted condensation within the main part of your refrigerator.

Unless you know for certain what will happen, I'd suggest using your freezer space for storing hops or other things more appropriate.  And like @mdma said, this is probably more appropriate in a hacking forum of sorts for appliances.

Answer (score 0):

I have a friend that told me he did this in college. I didnt believe him when he told be. But on reflection, I think if you turned the freezer portion off, the refridgerator would keep the entire space cold, but may have to work harder to do so.

I would be very interested to hear how it worked out :)